# Eager load a multiple indexes relationship with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently working on a project where I have to use a 10 years old database which is badly constructed.
Anyway I have two tables: one for the products and one for their colors. Every product is identified by a reference and every color is identified by its own reference + its product's one.
For instance I have a product which has the reference 123. This product has 3 colors: 123-01, 123-02 and 123-03. These two values are split in two columns: nocol (product reference) and nopat (color reference). 
I can't have a unique id for each color as the database is dropped every night so the ids are always changing (I know this is pretty weird).

For now I have three models: Product, Color and CartItem. My Color model has a one-to-one relationship with the Product model. My CartItem has a one-to-one relationship with my Color model which is defined like this:

```
public function color() {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Color', 'nocol', 'color_ref')->where('nopat', $this->product_ref);
}
```

This is working fine because I can retrieve the Color from the CartItem with a simple `$cartItem->color`. The problem is that it doesn't work with eager loading. When I try to retrieve my CartItems with something like this:

```
CartItem::with('product', 'color')->get();
```

I end up with a null relationship when I dump the result.

Is there any other way to write this kind of relationship when the index is two separate columns?

---

**EDIT 07-10**

As requested, here is a very simple view of the database. As I said I had to use an old database which I can't modify. The easiest way to solve my problem would be to add a unique ID to my Color table but I'm not able to do this.

My Product model has a unique id `pat_nopat`. One Product can have many colors. My Color model has two columns `col_nopat` and `col_nocol`. The `col_nopat` column references the Product ID. Together, the two columns are a unique ID for the Color model.

My OrderItem model references a Color by both `col_nopat` and `col_nocol` which are called `product_ref` and `color_ref`.

[image]

When I display the order history for a specific customer, I also display some information about the Color through the OrderItem model. The problem is that it executes too much queries because I can't find a way to eager load the relationship between the OrderItem and the Color.

---

**EDIT 07-11**

I tried to change my relationship using a join clause instead of a where clause. The eager loading works but the results are wrong.

If I have two CartItems with the same color reference but a different product reference, the results I get are wrong.
Let's say I have two CartItems like this:

```
product_ref | color_ref
----------- | ---------
1234        | 01
5678        | 01
```

I get the correct results with the where relationship except I can't eager load.

However, the join relationship returns 1234-01 for both rows because it takes the first result for each color reference.
If I take a look at the queries in the debugbar I get the following:

```
select * from `colors` inner join `cart_items` on `colors`.`col_nopat` = `cart_items`.`product_ref` where `colors`.`col_nocol` in ('01')
select * from `products` where `products`.`pat_nopat` in ('1234', '5678')
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple ERD with comments on the columns?

Comment: Sure I updated the question.

Comment: Knowing this, you might want to use [LaravelTreats](https://github.com/mopo922/LaravelTreats/tree/master/src/Model) in order to use composite PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a join? (By the way, isn't it a `belongsTo` relationship rather than `hasOne`?)

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Color::class, 'color_ref')
        ->join('order_items', 'colors.col_nopat', '=', 'order_items.product_ref');
}
```

---

After your edit I see the problem with this solution. It's always hard to deal with composite primary keys in Eloquent, as is (sort of) this case.

You can cheat a bit and eager-load all matching colors and then filter by `product_ref`. This way you avoid triggering separate queries per CartItem model. Consider this:

```
// Product.php
public function colors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Color::class, 'col_nopat', 'pat_nopat');
}

// ----

// CartItem.php
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_ref');
}

public function getColorAttribute()
{
    return $this->product->colors
        ->where('col_nopat', $this->product_ref)
        ->first();
}
```

Then load the relationship with `CartItem::with('product.colors')`, then you can do `$item->color`.

---

Alternative:

```
// CartItem.php
public function color()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Color::class, 'col_nocol', 'color_ref')
        ->select('colors.*')
        ->join('items', function ($join) {
            $join->on('colors.col_nocol', '=', 'items.color_ref');
            $join->on('colors.col_nopat', '=', 'items.product_ref');
        });
}

public function getColorAttribute()
{
    return $this->getRelation('color')
        ->where('col_nopat', $this->product_ref)
        ->first();
}
```

(In this you can avoid going through the `product` relationship.)

Comment: I would provide all the models in the question including their relation and test it in order to get the bounty :)

Comment: @ThomasMoors I would but it seems clear that OP already has that working. Only this `color` relationship was missing

Comment: You might be right, if that's the case disregard my comment :)

Comment: Thank you so much this actually works :) Looks like I have to wait 24 hours to award the bounty but I'll do for sure. @ThomasMoors thanks to you too ;)

Comment: Sure no problem!

Comment: I just double checked my results and it doesn't work. When I have multiple OrderItems with the same color reference (for instance product_ref = 10 / color_ref = 2 and product_ref = 12 / color_ref = 2) that would return the same product reference every time. I'm not sure if this is clear...

Comment: @MarcBellêtre no, I don't get it. Please post some sample data?

Comment: I added an example in the question. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Your first solution seems to work fine! I'm just gonna triple check this time :) I just had to change `col_nopat` and `product_ref` by `col_nocol` and `color_ref` in the `getColorAttribute` function.
However the second one doesn't work. I get an error saying that the relationship doesn't exist.
I'll let you know if something breaks otherwise I won't forgive to give you the bounty ;)

Answer (score 0):

Define the relationship as:

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Color', 'nocol', 'color_ref');
}
```

Then use [eager loading constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
CartItem::with(['product', 'color' => function ($q) use ($productRef) {
        $q->where('nopat', $productRef);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: `productRef` is on the `CartItem` table, so this wouldn't work the way you think.

Comment: That's right, I can't do it this way because I don't have productRef when I want to retrieve all my CartItems